# Why the Animator variable is all the time null?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Animations : MonoBehaviour
{
    public enum AnimatorStates
    {
        WALK, RUN, IDLE
    }

    private Animator _anim;

    void Start()
    {
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    public void PlayState(AnimatorStates state)
    {
        string animName = string.Empty;
        switch (state)
        {
            case AnimatorStates.WALK:
                animName = "Walk";
                break;
        }
        _anim.Play(animName);
    }
}
```

I used a break point.
After the line in the Start function _anim is not null.
But after the line:

```
_anim.Play(animName);
```

_anim is null.

And i have a "Walk" state in the Animator i added a new state and named it "Walk".

And this is how  i'm using the animations script from another script:

```
void Update()
    {
        if (MyCommands.walkbetweenwaypoints == true)
        {
            anims.PlayState(Animations.AnimatorStates.WALK);
            WayPointsAI();
            ReverseWayPointsAI();
        }

        DrawLinesInScene();
    }
```

But i can't figure out why the _anim is null and not playing the "Walk" state.

[image: Animator]

Comment: Are you sure the Animations script is activated before you try to call `PlayState`?

Comment: @CNuts in the script where i call the PlayState i did in the top private Animations anims; and then in the Start function anims = new Animations(); and then in the Update function when it's true it's calling the PlayState: anims.PlayState....

Comment: Ya but that's not what I'm talking about. If that script that calls `PlayState` is activated before the other script it's normal that you get a null value in `_anim`

Comment: But it's not i used a break point first it's running the script with the instance of the Animations script then it's getting to the Animations script Start function and make the line _anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); using a break point here i see that _anim is not null. Then i continue the game then i'm doing the action that make the condition to be true in the Update function in the other script then it's getting inside and call the PlayState and this time the _anim is null.

Comment: I also tried to add before the it's playing the Walk two lines: if (_anim == null)
            _anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); this two lines are before the line _anim.Play(animName); but i'm getting exception on _anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); null exception. Maybe something else make the problem maybe the animName ?

Comment: Try to move `_anim = GetComponent<Animator>();` to the Awake function.

Comment: I found the problem. Instead doing: anims = new Animations(); i'm doing now: anims = GetComponent<Animations>(); and this is working.